# Unable to install KB2670838

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-update

Trying to update a Server 2008 R2 Enterprise from IE9 to IE11. This is a VM.

Going through the prereq list for the life of me I can't get `KB270838` to install.

sfc /scannow is clean. Readiness tool is clean. Ran FixIt and it's clean. OS has the most current updates except IE 11 and this patch.

This is a clean install and I have many others with the same problem.

Event Log

```
Installation Failure: Windows failed to install the following update with error 0x80070002
```

CBS Log

```
2016-11-15 12:28:30, Info                  CBS    Failed to find file: x86_microsoft-windows-windowscodec_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.22948_none_98f63e7f1892a115\WindowsCodecs.dll [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
2016-11-15 12:28:30, Info                  CBS    Failed to gather all required files. [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
2016-11-15 12:28:30, Info                  CBS    Failed to gather all missing files for package: Microsoft-Windows-PlatformUpdate-Win7-SRV08R2-Package-TopLevel~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7.1.7601.16492 [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
2016-11-15 12:28:30, Info                  CSI    0000059c@2016/11/15:17:28:30.967 CSI Transaction @0xf6610c0 destroyed
2016-11-15 12:28:30, Error                 CBS    Failed to pre- stage package: Microsoft-Windows-PlatformUpdate-Win7-SRV08R2-Package-TopLevel~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7.1.7601.16492 [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
2016-11-15 12:28:30, Info                  CBS    Perf: Stage chain complete.
2016-11-15 12:28:30, Info                  CBS    Failed to stage execution chain. [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
2016-11-15 12:28:30, Error                 CBS    Failed to process single phase execution. [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
2016-11-15 12:28:30, Info                  CBS    WER: Generating failure report for package: Microsoft-Windows-PlatformUpdate-Win7-SRV08R2-Package-TopLevel~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7.1.7601.16492, status: 0x80070002, failure source: Stage, start state: Resolved, target state: Installed, client id: WindowsUpdateAgent
2016-11-15 12:28:30, Info                  CBS    Failed to query DisableWerReporting flag.  Assuming not set... [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
2016-11-15 12:28:30, Info                  CBS    Failed to add %windir%\winsxs\pending.xml to WER report because it is missing.  Continuing without it...
2016-11-15 12:28:30, Info                  CBS    Failed to add %windir%\winsxs\pending.xml.bad to WER report because it is missing.  Continuing without it...
2016-11-15 12:28:31, Info                  CBS    Reboot mark refs: 0
```

From this log I see the following file not found which produce 0x80070002 but I'm not sure what these are to download them.

`x86_microsoft-windows-windowscodec_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.22948_none_98f63e7f1892a115\WindowsCodecs.dll`

`Microsoft-Windows-PlatformUpdate-Win7-SRV08R2-Package-TopLevel~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7.1.7601.16492`

[image]

Comment: As codecs are normally used by the Windows Movie player you might try to install/reinstall the media features.

Comment: `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth`

Comment: The file is for a x86 's OS, but 2008R2 come only in x64. Normal it dont find the file, but odd if you selected the correct KB to install, as I see it in the last print screen, it's the x64 .cab..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Stop the BITS and Windows Updates service.

Go to C:\Windows\ and delete the SoftwareDistribution Folder

Open CMD (Command Prompt) and type: winmgmt /resetrepository

Start BITS and Windows Updates service.

Try again. Post any errors.

Comment: no change has been tried many times.

Comment: Please check your update history and find that if the KB3004394(12/10/2014) was installed, If yes, uninstall the kb3004394 and try again.

Comment: this update is not installed